# How do I hide the panels in fallback mode using the command line?

Tags: command-line, 12.04

I want to hide the panels via script.

in maverick I used 
          gconftool-2 --set "/apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0/auto_hide" --type bool "true"

now I tried

```
      gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout ...
```

but there is a problem:

```
     gsettings list-keys org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout
```

tells me:

```
     object-id-list
     toplevel-id-list
```

but in dconf editor there are 2 subfolder layers called toplevels and then top-panel /bottom-panel
I have no idea how to get there.

it should be

toplevels.top-panel auto_hide true

I tried all different things to get there...no way. does that mean you cannot change these values from commandline any more?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `gsettings` you can use `dconf` from the command line as well.

For example

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/toplevels/bottom-panel/auto-hide true
```

This will write the value `TRUE` to the `auto-hide` key.

If you need to see the keys in a path then use the `list` parameter

For example:

```
dconf list /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/toplevels/top-panel/
```

Remember to start with a `/` and end with a `/` for paths.