# command line for hiding and unhiding unity panel

Tags: unity, command-line

I use ubuntu 12.10 on a touchscreen with a digitizer pen to take notes and while I'm doing this I would rather to have all my desktop for this purpose. On the other hand while doing other stuff I would switch a lot between apps. So I want to make a shortcut on my keyboard to toggle the status of unity panel. I've tried the commands suggested here:
[Shortcut to change Launcher 'Hide' setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41241/shortcut-to-change-launcher-hide-setting)

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/launcher_hide_mode" 2
```

but it seems like the commands do not work. I installed the `gconf-editor` and changed the value of the variable manually, but that also doesn't help. The commands change the value in the gconf-editor though, but the panel is still not hidden. Is there something that I am missing?

I also changed the variable type to string and boolean, but still no success.

PS: I couldn't leave a comment there, so I had to ask it in a new question.

EDIT:

same result for the command

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/toplevels/bottom-panel/auto-hide true
```

from [How do I hide the panels in fallback mode using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120635/how-do-i-hide-the-panels-in-fallback-mode-using-the-command-line?rq=1)

Comment: Maybe a reason: Ubuntu has switched (or better: is switching) from gconf to dconf. IF it is still a usable setting install dconf-editor and see if it is in there (`gsettings` is used for dconf)

Comment: I also tried gsetting, but the only useful command I found was this: 'gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode 1', which tells me it doesn't recognize com.canonical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For 12.10

As Rinzwind mentioned in the comments, Ubuntu has migrated its settings from gconf to gsettings. The commands in the question you linked is valid for 12.04 and earlier, but not for 12.10 onwards.

The updated commands for hiding the Unity launcher would be:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-hide-mode 1
```

And for unhiding the Unity launcher:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-hide-mode 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this using `dconf watch /` and some other scripts. Weird thing is although the line seems to be accepted on 16.04, the unity launcher doesn't seem to autohide. Any ideas?