# How to switch off sidebar menu at thin clients based on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, ltsp, ltsp-client

I've got LTSP server based on ubuntu 12.04. I need to hide or disallow or switch off the launcher on thin clients forever (not only for one time, because every session does not save any data on server, even settings)

[image: Well, you know]

Is that any possibility to make this work?

Comment: Not possible. This is chosen in the settings. If you want it permanently, the setting need to be stored.

Comment: @Tim I can make some changes using ltsp-chroot on server and update settings in client image

Comment: Well change the settings, monitor the files that change and set them as "pinned", so all clients get them.

Comment: Ok, but I do not know what file should i change. I thought about gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session but opt/ltsp/i386 (directory where is all files of thin clients image) haven't got any session files

Answer (score 1):

You could always run a command when they login?

> The updated commands for hiding the Unity launcher would be:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 1
> ```
>
> And for unhiding the Unity launcher:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 0
> ```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/274473)